# Update value in the database when done editing using PHP/jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table something like this:

```
  Product    SellingPrice  Cost   Profit
 Product 1        49        45      4
 Product 2        54        50      4
```

When i put value in the profit column the sellingprice will calculate. I fetched the cost value from the database. I'm done working with the calculation using jQuery but I'm stuck on how to update it in the database. Could someone guide me about the server side implementation?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content Management System</title>    
    <script>
            //calculate the selling price
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('tr').each(function(){
                var result = 0;
                $(this).find("input[name=cost],input[name=profit]").each(function(){
                    result += (+$(this).val());
                });
                $(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").val(result).css("background-color", "green");
                });     
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td><center>ID</center></td>
                <td><center>Product</center></td>
                <td><center>Selling Price</center></td>
                <td><center>Current Cost</center></td>
                <td><center>Profit</center></td>
            </tr> 

            <?php

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, product, cost FROM inventory");
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $myrow[0]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $myrow[1]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='sellingprice' size='10' readonly='true'/>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='cost' size='10' value='$myrow[2]' readonly='true'/>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='profit' size='10' />"; ?>
                    </td>   
                </tr>   
                <?php
            }
                ?>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On another note you should never have columns in your database that can be calculated easily such as the "profit" one you have.

Comment: And ass a side-note to @ZeSimon's comment - instead, you could create a `VIEW` that generates the table you need. Also `<center>` is deprecated. You're probably looking for `<thead>` and `<th>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your html and create a new php file to handle your form submission.
in php get the values through $_GET[""] and insert them into table.

```
<body>
<form name="some_name" id="form1" action="somephpfilename.php">
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td><center>ID</center></td>
                <td><center>Product</center></td>
                <td><center>Selling Price</center></td>
                <td><center>Current Cost</center></td>
                <td><center>Profit</center></td>
            </tr> 

            <?php

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, product, cost FROM inventory");
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $myrow[0]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $myrow[1]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='sellingprice' size='10' readonly='true'/>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='cost' size='10' value='$myrow[2]' readonly='true'/>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='profit' size='10' />"; ?>
                    </td>   
                </tr>   
                <?php
            }
                ?>
        </table>
    </center>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update to db">
    <form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add form tag to your table rows and when form is submitted, you grab / validate incoming data and run UPDATE query on your table by ids. Also, you need to change your input elements to use Arrays:
    `echo "<input type='text' name='sellingprice[".$myrow[0]."]' size='10' readonly='true'/>";`

Something like that...

Comment: no, you have to code it yourself.
Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
Also, you need to add a condition to your PHP to detect the form being submitted for update. You can check $_POST superglobal for incoming update action value or so...